# SRA run data access

Tags: sequence-analysis, phylogenetics

Trying to download run data of Run accession **SRR2155174**. Here's the link: https://trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/sra/?run=SRR2155174
Please go to the link and go to the "Data Access" tab. Hereunder header "Name" you can find two links:
https://sra-downloadb.be-md.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sos1/sra-pub-run-5/SRR2155174/SRR2155174.1
https://sra-downloadb.st-va.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sos2/sra-pub-run-6/SRR2155174/SRR2155174.1
**Do these two links download the same data or they are for different purposes?**

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems just like two different mirrors contains the same SRA archive. If you still doubt, you can download both (its have relatively small size) and compare their md5sum.